# I want to get commits on a branch in bitbucket stash via rest api

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am trying to get commits on a particular branch in bitbucket stash.

1. Branch was initially branched from master to develop some features
2. after feature code was committed it was merged back to master
3. But the branch was not deleted, so I want to use Bitbucket rest API to get the exact commits on that particular feature branch.

I tried

```
https://<stash-url>/stash/rest/api/1.0/projects/<project-ID>/repos/<repo-slig>/compare/commits?from=<my-target-feature-branch>&to=master
```

which gives me

```
{
"values": [],
"size": 0,
"isLastPage": true,
"start": 0,
"limit": 25,
"nextPageStart": null
}
```

and the other url i tried is

```
https://<stash-url>/stash/rest/api/latest/projects/<project-ID>/repos/<repo-slug>/commits?until=<my-target-feature-branch>&limit=100
```

which gives me the whole commit history from master too.

can someone please help me? I am a newbie and I'm sure there is something wrong in my understanding of API docs

Comment: I know nothing about the Bitbucket API, but note that most Git commits are on many branches simultaneously. As a general rule, to limit commits, you tell Git: *get me ancestors of X, excluding ancestors of Y* where X and Y are any valid name for a commit, including branch names. Hence to list commits reachable from branch `feature` but not from branch `develop` you say: "yes to feature, no to develop" i.e. `develop..feature`.

Comment: Did you used pull request? If yes then maybe you can it with /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests (there are many options there, like direction etc), and then find commits of that PR with /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests/{pullRequestId}/commits?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
https://<stash-url>/stash/rest/api/latest/projects/<project-ID>/repos/<repo-slug>/commits?until=<my-target-feature-branch>&limit=0&start=0
```

See also:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Querying-the-last-commit-on-a-particular-branch-in-Bitbucket/qaq-p/577910

Comment: well, this also gives me commits even before the branch was created. i only want commits to this particular branch not any other commits from parent-branch

Comment: This might help https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-find-all-the-commits-made-on-a-branch/qaq-p/11842

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the list of commits only for provided branch:

```
GET https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{WORKSPACE}/{REPO}/commits?include={BRANCH}&exclude=master
```

See [BitBucket documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-commits/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-commits-get) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can! Using the tag:

> ?until=refs/heads/{branch-name}

My example:

```
curl -u <user>:<pass> -X GET "https://stash.xxx.com/rest/api/latest/projects/{project-key}/repos/{repo-slug}/commits?until=refs/heads/feature/ALMENGI-460"
```